# How to create new JDBC connection pool in glassfish

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I am trying to deploy my java EE project on glassfish server. But it shows the error to create a "jdbc connection pool" for my database access. Thus, I am trying to create a jdbc connection pool on glassfish,but I got the following error on the 2nd step:
[image: jdbc connection pool error on glassfish]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check the server.log for more details! What are the server.log files saying?

Comment: The problem is really obvious...